# Tell semantic to ignore header file

Tags: cedet, semantic

For good or for ill our project has some generated header files that contain binary data

```
const unsigned char __attribute__ ((aligned(4))) image[238560] = {
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, ...
...
}
```

Which are included to fill certain resources.

Is there a way to instruct cedet/semantic not to parse such files (ie not to lock up `:-/`)